# Find the global minimum of $ab+a+b$ subject to $a^2+b^2=25$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, maxima-minima

> Let $a,b$ be real numbers. İf  $a^2+b^2=25$  find minimum value of $ab+a+b$

---

My solution: $b=\sqrt{25-a^2}$
$f(a)=a\sqrt{25-a^2}+a+\sqrt{25-a^2}$  and I use $f'(a)=0$
But this way long and difficult to me. Is there any easy solution? Thanks.

Comment: ...... and we do have $a b + a + b=-13$ when $a=3,b=-4$

Answer (score 6):

Hint 1: Notice that
$$(a+b+1)^2=a^2+b^2+1+2ab+2a+2b=26+2(ab+a+b)$$
so there is an equivalent much simpler function to minimize.

Hint 2: Pythagorean triplets.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\thinspace a+b=m, \thinspace ab=n\thinspace $ then you have :

$$m^2-2n=25$$

This implies that :

$$
\begin{align}m+n&=m+\frac {m^2-25}{2}\\
&=\frac 12\left(m+1\right)^2-13\\
&≥-13\thinspace .\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 2):

You might consider using substitutions as another way.

Let $\thinspace a=m+n, \thinspace b=m-n$ , then you have :

$$
\begin{align}&a^2+b^2=25\\
\iff &m^2+n^2=\frac {25}{2}\end{align}
$$

This leads to :

$$
\begin{align}ab+a+b&=m^2-\left(\frac {25}{2}-m^2\right)+2m\\
&=2m^2+2m-\frac {25}{2}\\
&=\frac 12\left(2m+1\right)^2-13\\
&≥-13\thinspace .\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

We have that

$$a^2+b^2=25 \iff (a+b)^2=25+2ab \iff ab=\frac12(a+b)^2-\frac{25}2$$

and

$$ab+(a+b)=\frac12(a+b)^2+(a+b)-\frac{25}2=\frac12((a+b)+1)^2-13$$

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do these kind of problems is using [lagrange multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier)

That is, write $\mathcal{L}(a,b,\lambda)=ab+a+b+\lambda(a^2+b^2-25)$ and solve the system of equations
$$\begin{cases}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}a}\mathcal{L}=0\\\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}b}\mathcal{L}=0\\\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\lambda}\mathcal{L}=0\end{cases}$$

In our case, this would be the system
$$\begin{cases}b+1+2\lambda a=0\\a+1+2\lambda b=0\\a^2+b^2-25=0\end{cases}$$

which is easier to solve.

Comment: You should mention why, in this case, you can identify the global minimizer among the solutions of that system. In general, the minimizer may not be a stationary point of the Lagrangian or, even if it is, you may need additional work to actually prove that the minimum is global.